# PDO rowCount and fetchColumn both not returning correct result

Tags: php, pdo

I've tried various things to get this short bit of code to work. What it does is it connects to the database via PDO and then selects all rows that match a post variable. If there is more than 0 rows, update the licensekey rows to be "used" and echo true.

I have tried both rowcount and fetchcolumn and count(*) for sql, and none of shown any differences. In MySQL itself, I have used a valid licensekey and it indeed returns one row.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['licensekey'])) {

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=validation", "test", "test");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$search = ("SELECT * FROM validated WHERE activationkey=:lk AND used='0'");
$result = $db->prepare($search);
$result->bindParam(":lk", $_POST['licensekey']);
$result->execute();

if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
    $used = ("UPDATE validated SET used='1' WHERE validated.activationkey=:lk");
    $result2 = $db->prepare($used);
    $result2->bindParam(":lk", $_POST['licensekey']);
    $result2->execute();

    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

$db = null;
} else {
    exit();
}
?>
```

Every time it will return false no matter what.

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Are you certain it is connected to the same database as you have tested in your MySQL client? You do have exceptions enabled, so a problem would surface before the `echo "false"` executes.  If you remove the `activationkey=:lk AND` from the query and comment out the `bindParam()` call to run it without parameters, is `rowCount()` still zero assuming some rows exist in the table?

Comment: `rowCount()` does work with some versions of MySQL for SELECT queries, I've tested against both an old 5.1 and 5.6.

Comment: I've commented out the `bindparam` and changed the query so that it just does `SELECT * FROM validated` - It now returns true, but that's where I'm still confused. The licensekey is posted because I check with `isset` so it should be in there and good to go. The licensekey is exactly the same as I copy-pasted it, but it will return false in the case it is posted. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Are you sure it is the same, without anything like trailing whitespace? do `var_dump($_POST['licensekey'])` and check the output as well as the length. Ensure that the string length is exactly as it should be, not followed by space or linebreaks, and verify the same is true of what is stored in the table. Use `trim($_POST['licensekey'])` if whitespace is present.

Comment: also make sure that the POST array contains a value and that the form method is indeed POST. also use `!empty` instead of `if(isset($_POST['licensekey']))` so `if(!empty($_POST['licensekey']))` and do a var_dump as previously stated. Also make sure the column's length is long enough, otherwise it will fail silently. Error reporting might help too http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: imo, fetch the data. It is one row. just do `fetchAll`  and check the table for being empty or not. You then do not care about counts being set correctly or not by the database driver as you have the actual data to check?

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can't see how many records selected in DB with rowCount function. As i read in PHP Documentation many of select queries doesn't return how many rows affected by query with rowCount method. Check it for more information : http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

As doc says you can use fetchColumn method.