# Print result of prepared statement php (mysqli::num_rows not being set correctly)

Tags: php, mysqli

I've recently updated from normal statements

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id from users WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
```

to prepared statements(security)

```
prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
```

I followed some tutorials, but this still won't work:

```
public function isUserRegistered($user_id) {
        print $user_id;
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($user_id);
            $stmt->fetch();     

            $no_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
            print $no_of_rows;
            $stmt -> close();
            if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
                print "Finally";
                // user already registered
                return true;
            } else {
                print "Stupid";
                // user is not registered
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The supplied id exists, because I can see it in the console being printed. The  `if ($stmt->execute())`  is being executed, but for some reason nothing comes back.

How can I solve this and how can I print the result?

I've also tried:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $user_id);
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any error? Did you try to execute the same query manually and did it return any results?

Comment: Yes, it does return a row. And no, I don t get any errors.

Comment: Could you add the error checking to your question, please? Maybe you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm new to php. What do you mean by that ? I'm using postman, and I can see in the console that it's printing the id,0 rows and STUPID  `123210Stupid`

Comment: Just add how're you checking the query errors in your code. It's obvious it returns 0 rows if there's an error.

Comment: I don't have anything like that. How would suck a thing look like?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy quite contrary, it won't return anything in case of error.

Comment: I see. You wrote you didn't get any errors, so it wasn't because there were no errors, but because you simply ignore them. Error messages are one of the most important things when you're programming. Ignoring them is very bad idea. In many cases, there is no other way to find what's wrong without checking the error.

Comment: Well, console has no reason to complain. Check the [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Also make sure you have enabled PHP error reporting and displaying (this alone wouldn't help in your case, but it's absolutely critical for development).

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean by the console. Also I don't understand what you mean by having the if statements, since it's not related to the error reporting at all.

Comment: I do have a php_error.log and I don't get any errors. If there were any errors with the query, the `if  ($stmt->execute())` would complain. I mean, that's how I see it, and nothing would get printed. Then again, I don't know much php so I can't argue too much.

Comment: @RyanVincent I tried with a different variable too, and I get nothing back.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel Check my answer to learn how to check the query errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110158/discussion-between-bogdan-daniel-and-ryan-vincent).

Comment: Your other question in chat. I like things to be easy to read and understand at a 'higher level' and 'hide' common details. So, I tend to put details in functions (or views). With that in mind: maybe interesting: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/stored-function-haversine-distance-computation. It is easier to understand and debug as a separate function. You can always edit it to be inline if the overhead of the function call is excessive later. imo, It is easier to understand and change while you develop the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `$stmt->num_rows` is *not valid* unless you **store the result first** as explained here:  [mysqli_stmt::$num_rows - Return the number of rows in statements result set](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

The **`fetch` works fine** and returns the rows of data as expected. Alas, the `mun_rows` property is zero so the `isUserRegistered` method fails. Even though it returned the correct data.

**Note: changed to actually check the returned value from the `fetch`.**

Conclusion:

- Use `$stmt->store_result()` to ensure `$stmt->num_rows` is useful.
- use the actual returned data to ensure it returned what you expected?

Example code: http://pastebin.com/wDvAru39

Final `isUserRegistered` code I used:

Code:

```
class UserRegister {

    protected $conn = null;

    public function __construct($dbConnection) 
    {
        $this->conn = $dbConnection;
    }   

    public function isUserRegistered($user_id) {
        print $user_id;
        $result_user_id = null;
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            $stmt->store_result(); // need this to force the `num_rows` to be correct

            $stmt->bind_result($result_user_id);
            $stmt->fetch();     

            $no_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows; 

            var_dump(__METHOD__, 
                    'input user id: '. $user_id, 
                    'found user id: '. $result_user_id, 
                    'reported number of rows: '. ($no_of_rows),  __FILE__.__LINE__);

            $stmt->close();
            if (!empty($result_user_id)) { // check the returned data not the indicator
                print "Finally";
                // user already registered
                return true;
            } else {
                print "Stupid";
                // user is not registered
                return false;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Output from the var_dump statements:

Note: the `store_result` statement.

```
12321
string 'UserRegister::isUserRegistered' (length=30)
string 'input user id: 12321' (length=20)
string 'found user id: 12321' (length=20)
string 'reported number of rows: 1' (length=26)
string 'K:\developer\testmysql\index4.php78' (length=35)
Finally
string 'isUserRegistered :
```

Comment out the 'store_result' statement gives:

```
12321
string 'UserRegister::isUserRegistered' (length=30)
string 'input user id: 12321' (length=20)
string 'found user id: 12321' (length=20)
string 'reported number of rows: 0' (length=26)
string 'K:\developer\testmysql\index4.php79' (length=35)
Finally
string 'isUserRegistered : true
```

Note: number of reported rows is zero.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel, Thanks. It was difficult to find the fault for those not familiar with `mysqli`. It turned out to be interesting.

Comment: The issue is that $stmt->num_rows is not ever needed.

Comment: @YourCommonSense,  **that we agree totally on!!!** Especially if you see my comments in other questions! i.e. [Here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829578/pdo-rowcount-and-fetchcolumn-both-not-returning-correct-result#comment61234089_36829578). I was explaining why it wasn't being set correctly. I really thought I  did explain that checking the fetched data was the only way to go. :) I even mentioned it in the chat!

Answer (score 0):

Most tutorials are written by people whose knowledge is scarcely better than yours. And using num_rows() in the code is a sure sign of such a tutorial.

In fact, in PHP you don't need such a function ever.

Take, for example, your code. **There is already a variable that can tell  whether a user is registered or not** - a selected user id. Which you can just return from the function. Or you can use just a constant value like this

```
public function isUserRegistered($user_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($found);
    $stmt->fetch();     
    return $found;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll modify it now. Could you update with a print statement that could print the result ?

Comment: You shouldn't have any print statements inside of a function called isUserRegistered(). You have to use this function in a condition and you may print something inside this condition.

Comment: I won't have it in the future, it's just for me to see in the console if the right things are returned. Just like I was printing 'Finally' in my function.

Comment: I tried to print the returned value, but I still get nothing. And I want to specify that this `SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = '12321'`  works.

Comment: Mine was already like that and I'm still not able to print anything that is returned.

Comment: then you have to debug your code. I tested this one and it worked, printing 1 for the existing user.

Comment: How do you print it ?

Comment: Just like any other variable. echo $found;

Comment: .. it's not working. Where might the problem come from ?